# how to calculate area under power spectrum to test if it is equal to rms value (FFT, python, signal processing)

Tags: python, fft, physics, frequency-analysis

I have this problem for physics class, I'm stuck on the last point.

Generate a signal of 2s length with sampling frequency 500 Hz that contains 
(i) a white background noise as produced by a resistance of 1MW at 300K and a bandwidth of 10 kHz, 
(ii) a sine wave signal at frequency 80 Hz with amplitude 12 mV, 
(iii) a sine wave signal at frequency 170 Hz with amplitude 6 mV.
- Calculate the power-spectrum from the signal in units of V2/Hz.
 Test if the area of the power spectrum is equal to the rms value of the signal.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random 
#Generate a signal of 2s length with sampling frequency 500 Hz that contains

#sampling frequency 500 Hz
Fs=500 #the number of points taken 

#Generate a signal of 2s length
time=2
t=np.linspace(0,time,Fs*time) 



# (i) a white background noise as produced by a resistance of 1MW at 300K and a badwidth of 10kz
Kb=1.3806504e-23 #Boltzman's constant
T=300 #temperature kelving
R=1000 #Ohms resistance
DF=10000 #bandwith HZ
N=np.power((4*Kb*DF*R*T),0.5) #Noise in VOLTS

#Noise in uV from V
N=N
print ('Noise in uV: ' + str(N))

#the noise should move from twice its height, to -2 times its height... 2000 point up 2000 down, normalized with e-3

Noise=N*1e-3*np.asarray(random.sample(range(-2000,2000),len(t))) #array of random noise, size Fs makes noise from 0.8 to -0.8 uV


#(ii) a sine wave signal at frequency 80 Hz with amplitude 12 mV

#frequency 80 Hz
f1 = 80 #sine wave signal at frequency 80 Hz

#amplitude 12 mV
a1=12e-6 #amplitude 12 microV

# a sine wave signal
x1 = a1*np.sin(2*np.pi*t*f1) #sin wave from time formula (the t gives it the array shape)



#♦(iii)a sine wave signal at frequency 170 Hz with amplitude 6 mV

#frequency 170 Hz
f2=170 #a sine wave signal at frequency 170 Hz
#with amplitude 6 mV
a2=6e-6 # with amplitude 6 mV  IVE PUT IT IN VOLTS NOT uV
#a sine wave signal 
x2=a2*np.sin(2*np.pi*t*f2) #sin wave from time formula 


#- Calculate the power-spectrum from the signal in units of V2/Hz and dB. 

#total signal 
x=x2+x1#+Noise

#number of frequencies to look at
nfft=1024 #number of frequencies

#do the fft
X=np.fft.fft(x,nfft)


#new normalized version, Mx is the normalized X
Mx=abs(X)*2*(Fs*time)/(np.square(Fs*time))
Mx=Mx[1:nfft//2]

#cut away the second half because its an fft
X=X[1:nfft//2]

#create a vector for the frequencies, normalized
F=np.arange(0,nfft//2-1)*Fs/nfft


#creates the root mean square single complex value, for the rms. 
rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(Mx**2))
rms=[rms]*len(X)

#plot the wave 
plt.plot(t,x1+x2+Noise)
plt.title('Noise, 80HZ 170HZ')
plt.ylabel('microvolts')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.show()
#FFT vs the frequencies, normalized in microvolts squared
plt.plot(F,Mx)
plt.plot(F,rms)
plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Power Specturm of a Sine Wave')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel(('Power uV^2'))
plt.show()
```

AT this point I have to:  Test if the area of the power spectrum is equal to the rms value of the signal. I thought like this:

```
#area of power spectrum: 
area=sum(Mx)
```

however, when I compare it with rms, I don't get the same result? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The power spectrum is proportional to `abs(X)` squared, so `Mx` does not have dimensions of energy.

Comment: after normalization Mx should be the power spectrum ? in units of energy right? V^2/Hz 
this was the definition of Mx I used.

Mx=abs(X)*2*(Fs*time)/(np.square(Fs*time))
Mx=Mx[1:nfft//2]

so the code: area=sum(Mx) should give the sum of all the powers?

Comment: It still won't have *dimensions* of energy. Power = |amplitude|^2.

Comment: ah I see, I read my own code as abs(X)**2 instead of abs(X)*2....
So what is an appropriate Mx function so that I get the proper power function normalized ? 
Mx=abs(X)**2 -with what else multiplied by it?

Comment: If you normalize the amplitude to max 1 then the max power will also be 1. Linear factors don't really mean very much physically though...

Comment: I ended up using a different normalizations, this is the code: 

{normalf=2/N #FFt coefficient nomalization 
factorc=np.fft.fft(Vt) #calculate the complex FFt coefficients 
absc=abs(c) # calculate the magnitude of the FFt coefficient 
phic=np.angle(c) #calulate the pahse angle
c=c[0:int(N)//2]  #cuts off the negative frequencies 
cnorm=abs(c)*normalf #multiplies the coefficients with a normalization 
p=(abs(cnorm))**2
p=p*T/2 #additional nomlalization accounting for one sided spectrum 
fv=np.arange(0, int(N)//2)/T #calculates the vector containign the frequencies}